# A tune included in Britten's Moment Musicales

Tags: classical-music

I am trying to identify a tune I heard in Britten's Moments musicales. It is a classical tune familiar to me, kind of light and bouncy with some syncopation. I know he uses a lot of Rossini in that piece but I don't think it's Rossini. I have not been able to find this piece listed in descriptions of Britten's piece. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I guess, you are asking for *Soirées musicales*. Literature only mentions Rossini as used source material. I'm afraid this will be considered as identification question and might be closed for that reason.